# How to create download hit counter with database in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

What an easy to count how many times a file has been downloaded.
The file details are stored in MySQL database and the files in a folder on the server.
The files are linked for download via the anchor tag

```
href=upload/$row['file']
```

generating as an example **filename.zip**
I was thinking about adding another field to the files table called downloads, somehow when the link is clicked mark that file as `$row['downloads'] +1` and update the downloads field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that approach is great. When the download is initiated, the counter can be incremented:

```
update file set downloads = downloads + 1 where file_path = ?
```

If you want to store additional information about each download (such as the time of download) you could have a download table with a foreign key linking each download action to the corresponding file.